# What cable do I buy for my 2nd monitor?

Tags: display, hdmi, vga

Windows pc user here

I have a gtx 1050 ti graphics card and as of right now there's 1 hdmi monitor connected to it.
I received a free 2nd screen from my uncle i'd like to use but it's VGA.

My graphics card only has 3 outputs:
1x hdmi
1x dvi
1x dp
is it possible to connect my 2nd VGA screen to my GPU? I have no idea what cable to buy.
I have a HDMI to VGA adapter, but yeah, I only have 1 hdmi output. Should I get a splitter? Or something totally else?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with a Gigabyte GTX 1050Ti
in the end i used this adapter

[image: adapter]

I got mine from  [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com.mx/dp/B00Z08TZNU/?coliid=ITC7DUSBFHFTT&colid=3OWNCMM1YKB3S&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it)

This particular one is from Ranke and converts your Display output to a VGA and it works fine

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Using a HDMI splitter won't solve your problem, unless you want the same thing to be displayed on both monitors (you won't be able to use them as 2 separate monitors).

Without knowing what *type* of DVI output your GPU provides, your safest option is to get a Displayport to VGA adapter.